# Best representation of 4 index object with an integer number

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I am trying to represent a variable(symbol) with 4 dummy indices (A_ijkl) with an integer number (4ijkl where i,j,k,l can run from 0 to 9. e.g. 41586, 45862, 47785, etc.). This number is saved in an array that may have other variables that represent other symbols (3xx,5xxx..etc). Since the base for the symbol, I am trying to extract the indices is 40000 any number after that represents an index that I need to collect. For example 41256-> Symbol:4 Index:[1,2,5,6].

```
g1=41541 #test 
t1=g1-40000
bs=1000  
lst_indx=[]
while t1:
  indx=int(t1/bs)
  t1=t1-(indx*bs)
  bs=bs/10
  lst_indx.append(indx)
print(lst_indx)
```

This code produce: [1, 5, 4, 1]

I know there are python routines to do the same thing I am trying to do. Like for example:

```
g1=41541 #test 
t1=g1-40000
res = list(map(int, str(t1)))
print(res)
```

My question is what is the more efficient and best memory saving way to extract the indices. I will be doing this for an array with millions of numbers that represent symbols with 1, 2, 3 or 4 indices.

Answer (score 0):

Since the string conversion of an integer is done with a built-in function written in C, it would be more efficient than an implementation in Python:

```
res = list(str(g1)[1:])
```